# Python pd.DataFrame() not responding

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am using Anaconda Spyder. When I want to do the following code, it shows no responding. I did not why. This line of code is the example in textbook and it can work in my friend's Spyder.

```
    import pandas as pd
    data=pd.DataFrame()
```

Everytime when I want to define like it, my Spyder will stop responding. I wonder why......

Comment: Can you run other pandas commands?

Comment: Yes, I can run other pandas commands.

Comment: Can you try this: `df2 = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5))` and see what df2 outputs?

Comment: df2 is a 10*5 matrix in my output.

Comment: Is anyone who can help me here? It is so inconvenient that I can not define an empty dataframe variable.

Comment: What version of spyder are you using? This issue seems prevalent in version 2.6